# Extract word from text, assign to variable and use variable in conditions shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file `ListOfFiles.txt` which has below values,

```
ABC_123456_AIRTEL_20210821.csv
ABC_123478_AIRTEL_20210821.csv
ABC_123490_AIRTEL_20210821.csv
```

I want to extract `AIRTEL` word from an above line from files, which I'm doing like,

```
while read filename; do
   echo ${filename} | tail -n1 |cut -d -d"." -f1|cut -d "_" -f3
   vers="`${filename} | tail -n1 |cut -d -d"." -f1|cut -d "_" -f3`"
   if [[ "${vers}" == "AIRTEL" ]]
   then
       echo "Yes yes yes"
   else
      echo "no no no"
   fi
   echo "${vers}"
done < ListOfFiles.txt
```

The first echo is returning `AIRTEL` as I need but when I assign that to variable and try to use it in conditions it's coming blank.

Comment: `vers` is not the same as `vars` you know.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks @Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work (untested).

```
ls | while read filename
do
   vers=$( echo ${filename} | cut -d"." -f1 | cut -d "_" -f3 )
   if [[ "${vers}" == "AIRTEL" ]]
   then
       echo "yes yes yes"
   else
      echo "no no no"
   fi
   echo "${vers}"
done < ListOfFiles.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using external commands. Bash parameter expansions can do this.

```
while read filename; do
   vers="${filename#ABC_*_}" # removing the prefix
   vers="${vers%_*.csv}" # removing the suffix
   if [[ "${vers}" == "AIRTEL" ]]
   then
       echo "Yes yes yes"
   else
      echo "no no no"
   fi
   echo "${vers}"
done < ListOfFiles.txt
```

In bash manual [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) **${parameter#word}** and **${parameter%word}**.

Comment: This also works as expected! Thanks @Alireza